# A way to match a SSHA hash using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match four hashes that look like this:

```
{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
{SSHA}QhikpbGFa5NAckbjcZ_K_WoJNh4=
{SSHA}5_DNVWsyofo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c=
{MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-pIEaHNhv39sSN7c=
```

I've successfully matched the first two with this regular expression: `\D{5,}[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+\(?=` however I am unable to get a full match on the third or the fourth one. What is a better regular expression to match the given hashes?

Comment: Not sure, try [`re.findall(r'(\{[^{}]*}[a-zA-Z0-9][\w/-]+)=', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/oAbXnh/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Probably should of mentioned this in the question, the `=` isn't always there, can I compensate for it being there or not being there?

Comment: Ok, just remove it - [`\{[^{}]*}[a-zA-Z0-9][\w/-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/oAbXnh/2). Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `\D{5,}` matches 5 or more non-digit chars, and then `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches an ASCII letter or digit and `\w+` matches 1+ letters/digits/`_`. So, if you have `-` or `/` in the string, it won't get matches. Or if the first 5 chars contain a digit.

I suggest the following pattern:

```
 \{[^{}]*}[a-zA-Z0-9][\w/-]+=?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oAbXnh/3).

It matches:

- `\{[^{}]*}` - a `{`, then 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}` (note you may further precise it: `\{\w+}` to match `{`, 1 or more letters/digits/`_`, and then `}`, or even `\{(?:SS?HA|MD5)}` to match `SHA`, `SSHA` or `MD5` enclosed with `{...}`)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an ASCII letter or digit
- `[\w/-]+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `=?` - an optional, 1 or 0 occurrences (due to the `?` quantifier) `=` symbols (greedy `?` makes it match a `=` if it is found).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/zRowbw):

```
import re
s = """
TEXT {SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
{SSHA}QhikpbGFa5NAckbjcZ_K_WoJNh4= and some more
{SSHA}5_DNVWsyofo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c text here
{MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c= maybe."""
rx = r"\{[^{}]*}[a-zA-Z0-9][\w/-]+=?"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=', '{SSHA}QhikpbGFa5NAckbjcZ_K_WoJNh4=', '{SSHA}5_DNVWsyofo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c', '{MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c=']
```

Comment: I need it to either catch the `=` if it's there, or skip it if it's not, I think `(?=)` would do this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
\{[SHAMD5]{3,4}\}[^=]+=?
```

It will match a { then 3 or 4 characters that are the combinations you have listed of characters.  You can change that to [A-Z0-9] to broaden it, but I like to keep it tighter to start.  Then a }.  Then all (at least 1) non = characters.  Ending with an optional = character.  Here is my python demo:

```
import re

textlist = [
"{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M="
,"{SSHA}QhikpbGFa5NAckbjcZ_K_WoJNh4="
,"{SSHA}5_DNVWsyofo-oIEzHnhv30rSN7c="
,"{MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-pIEaHNhv39sSN7c="
,"{MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-pIEaHNhv39sSN7c"
,"test for break below"
,"{WORD}stuff="
,"{MD55/DNVWwyafo-pIEaHNhv39sSN7c="
,"MD5}5/DNVWwyafo-pIEaHNhv39sSN7c="
]

for text in textlist:
    if re.search("\{[SHAMD5]{3,4}\}[^=]+=?", text):
        print ("match")
    else:
        print ("no soup for you")
```

Note the end of the list has a few tests to make sure the regex doesn't just succeed on anything random.